# Combine - bind a stream into another and handle side effects while doing it

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to learn `Combine`. I know the terms and the basic concept theoretically. But when trying to work with it, I am lost.

1. I am trying to do is map an `Input` stream of events to `Output` stream of state. Is there a way to bind the result of the map to `outputSubject`? I am trying to make it work with `sink` but is there a better way?
2. Also is there an operator equivalent of RxSwift's `withLatestFrom`?

```swift
import Combine

class LearnCombine {
  typealias Input = PassthroughSubject<Event, Never>
  typealias Ouput = AnyPublisher<State, Never>

  let input: Input
  var output: Ouput

  private var outputSubject: CurrentValueSubject<State, Never>
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {

    self.input = PassthroughSubject()
    self.outputSubject = CurrentValueSubject(.initial)
    self.output = outputSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()

    transformPipeline()
  }

  private func transformPipeline() {
    input
      .map { event in
        mapEventToState(event, with: outputSubject.value)
      }
      .handleOutput { state in
        handleSideEffects(for: state) // Also, how do I access the event here if I needed?
      }
      .sink {
        outputSubject.send($0)
      }
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }

  func mapEventToState(_ event: Event, with state: State) -> State {
    // Some code that converts `Event` to `State`
  }
} 

extension Publisher {
  func handleOutput(_ receiveOutput: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> Publishers.HandleEvents<Self> {
    handleEvents(receiveOutput: receiveOutput)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sink` to assign a value to a `CurrentValueSubject`, I would use `assign`.

If you want to do something with the values in the middle of a pipeline you can use the `handleEvents` operator, though if you look in the documentation you'll see that the operator is listed as a debugging operator because generally your pipeline should not have side effects (building it from pure functions is one of the primary benefits.

Just reading the description of `withLatestFrom` in the RX documentation, I think the equivalent in combine is `combineLatest`

Here's your code, put into a Playground, and modified a bit to  illustrates the first two points:

```
import Combine

struct Event {
    var placeholder: String
}


enum State {
    case initial
}

class LearnCombine {
  typealias Input = PassthroughSubject<Event, Never>
  typealias Ouput = AnyPublisher<State, Never>

  let input: Input
  var output: Ouput

  private var outputSubject: CurrentValueSubject<State, Never>
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {

    self.input = PassthroughSubject()
    self.outputSubject = CurrentValueSubject(.initial)
    self.output = outputSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()

    transformPipeline()
  }

  private func transformPipeline() {
    input
      .map { event in
          self.mapEventToState(event, with: self.outputSubject.value)
      }
      .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { value in
          debugPrint("Do something with \(value)")
      })
      .assign(to: \.outputSubject.value, on: self)
      .store(in: &cancellables)

  }

  func mapEventToState(_ event: Event, with state: State) -> State {
      return .initial
    // Some code that converts `Event` to `State`
  }
}

extension Publisher {
  func handleOutput(_ receiveOutput: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> Publishers.HandleEvents<Self> {
    handleEvents(receiveOutput: receiveOutput)
  }
}
```